# Same encrypted Text with AES must result in different length

Tags: c#, aes

I use this sample code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

**The AESCryptor is my own class with the original code from the above msdn link. It just wraps the Decrypt/encrypt methods NOT more.**

Thats how I call the decrypt/encrypt methods:

```
string plainText1 = "This is my sample plain text";
string plainText2 = "This is my sample plain text";

// Create a new instance of the AesManaged
// class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
// vector (IV).
using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged())
{
    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
    byte[] encrypted = AESCryptor.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(plainText1, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

    byte[] encrypted2 = AESCryptor.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(plainText2, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

}
```

My result that I expect is that both (encrypted and encrypted2) byte arrays have of course the same length but gets filled up with "zeros" so when I encode the byte[] with Base64 I get different looking strings.

How can I do that? Setting `myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;` Did not help.

Comment: Forget about the Base64 comment from me. I just would like to know how I get 2 byte arrays with different content for the same plain text.

Comment: What is `AESCryptor`? That's not a standard class as far as I know... please produce a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This is just my class with the implementation from the microsoft sample not more. If you look at the msdn sample you have my class.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I've copied and pasted your code and the MSDN code, and looked at `encrypted` and `encrypted2`, and they're equal. Please show a short but complete program that *does* demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Elisabeth Please include your class. Just so we can be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get different results for the same key and plaintext, you need to use a different IV.

By the look of it, to do this with a single `AesManaged` instance, you need to call `myAes.GenerateIV()` between your two encryption calls.

If you create a *new* `AesManaged`, you get a *new* key and a *new* IV for free, which may also achieve what you want.

Don't forget to record your key and IVs, because you won't be able to decrypt your messages without them.

Comment: My spidey sense says this is the answer. It's always in the code that "definitely doesn't make any difference".

Comment: @Rawling Yes that was my problem that I had to fix.